# installing tools for apache cordova for visual studio 2013 - CTP3

Tags: javascript, cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova, websocket4net

I am using visual studio 2013 ultimate running on a 64-bit windows 7 home premium. I wanted to write JavaScript code, when I tried to create a new JavaScript Project, It redirected me to Install the "Tools for Apache Cordova for Visual Studio". The installation completed successfully but showed an error in the end. The error was:

> Joyent Node.js:
>   Invalid command line argument. Consult the Windows Installer SDK for detailed command line help.  "

Now, I tried to create a new Project by selecting "JavaScript" form the "New Project" window. There was only one sub-option called "Blank App (Apache Cordova)". I selected it and clicked finish, bit then it showed all these errors:

> We've detected issues with your system's environment configuration
>      Joyent node.js - software is missing from your computer.
>      Apple iTunes - software is missing from your computer.
>      WebSocket4Net - software is missing from you computer.
>    You may also have to configure it after installation.

I fixed the error related to joyent node.js and iTunes by manually installing the two, but the problem with the WebSocket4Net still persists.

I've already installed `WebSocket4Net`, using both the "vs2013_mda0.3" setup and manually. This has not worked. I even tried to repair the installation, by using the "vs2013_mda0.3" setup, but it made things even worse.

Comment: Are you experiencing errors when you deploy and debug your project on Ripple?  if you are able to successfully debug on Ripple, the Websocket4Net issue report could be a false failure caused by a stale settings file and can be safely ignored.   What became worse after you tried to repair your installation?

Comment: I didn't try to deploy my project on Ripple. All I did was to start a new project to see this "WebSocket4Net" error. When I repaired the installation, VS lost track of environment variables (related to Tools for Apache Cordova, the installation directories of JDK, android-SDK, apache-ant and GIT) that were set when I installed it for the first time. I had to set these variables again. I don't know if anything else broke, 'cause these are the only ones I could find immediately.

Comment: The dependency report that is alerting you to the WebSocket4Net issue is meant to proactively alert you to issues found in your environment that will cause problems.  If there is a bug in the code that checks for these issues, it could be flagging something incorrectly.  That is what I want to find out - whether the issue is with your install of WebSocket4Net or an error in the dependency code itself.  You can test this by attempting to build your project and deploy to Ripple.  if it works, WebSocket4Net is fine.  If it fails, further investigation is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with the installer, a bug maybe. The latest update (Visual Studio Update 5 (2013.5)) fixes these bugs. After updating, I didn't get any of these errors.

Also, TypeScript Projects cannot be created on Windows 7 using visual studio 2013 or lower. You have to either upgrade the OS to windows 8 or later.